# Mvvmcross 7.0.0: using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Core not found

Tags: xamarin, namespaces, mvvmcross

I want to clear some troubles with adding MVVM cross 7.0.0 in an empty project (Xamarin.Forms). I had followed this guide from MVVM cross docs: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarin-forms-version
By the way, they didn't add actual MVVM cross ver for this tutorial :( So now I'm facing issue with the invalid package name in Forms Android project, so I couldn't use "MvxFormsAndroidSetup" and "MvxFormsAppCompatActivity".

Does someone know how to fix it?

[VS error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taqR3.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because your Android Project targetting `monodroid9.0` or lower. When you're upgrading to MvvmCross 7.x, you have to set your Android-Target version to `monodroid10.0` or higher. As you can see in the picture, with android 9, it didn't recognize the mvvmcross-nugget.

[image]

Look at the [release-news](https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-7.0.0-release/) to see all changes;

Comment: Thank you! I've already downgraded to 6.0.0 so it's gone, but your answer helps me to understand actual reasons.